# Facing problems with the atoi function if used repeatedly

Tags: c

I have to find the frequency of digits {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} in a given string, I'm using **atoi** function  to convert the character to an integer and I'm having problems with the **atoi** function when the input string is large (tried this with different test cases of varying length),

for example if the input string is

```
1v88886l256338ar0ekk
```

my code works properly and the answer is

```
1 1 1 2 0 1 2 0 5 0
```

where the 1st digit indicates the frequency of 0 and so on upto 9,

but if the input string is

```
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
```

upon reaching the end of the string the **atoi** function returns wrong values

for example,

my code uses **atoi** to convert **char text** to an integer and stores it into **int num**

at the beginning the function works fine,

```
text is 9 num is 9 
text is 1 num is 1 
text is 3 num is 3 
text is 9 num is 9 
text is 7 num is 7 
text is 9 num is 9 
text is 3 num is 3 
text is 3 num is 3 
text is 0 num is 0 
text is 8 num is 8 
text is 0 num is 0 
.
.
.
```

and upon nearing the very end of the string the function returns

```
.
.
. 
text is 2 num is 2 
text is 4 num is 4 
text is 0 num is 0 
text is 3 num is 30 
text is 6 num is 60 
text is 1 num is 10 
text is 1 num is 10 
text is 7 num is 70 
text is 0 num is 0 
text is 6 num is 61 
text is 5 num is 51 
text is 5 num is 51 
text is 2 num is 21 
text is 0 num is 1
text is 7 num is 71  
text is 0 num is 1 
text is 0 num is 1 
text is 3 num is 31
```

If I replace `int num = atoi(&text)` with `int num = text - '0'` my program works perfectly for all test cases,

so can someone please tell me what went wrong and whether I have used the function incorrectly.
Please keep in mind I just want to know why **atoi** didn't work, hence I'm not looking for replacements for the function.

I've included the snippet of my code below

```css
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    int arr[10] = {0};
    char text;
   text = getchar();
   while(text != EOF)
   {
       if(isdigit(text))
       {
           printf("text is %c ",text);
           int num = atoi(&text);
           printf("num is %d\n ",num);
           for(int i =0; i<10;i++)
           {
               if(num==i)
               {
                   arr[i]++;
                   //printf("arr[%d] is %d\n", i,arr[i]);
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       text = getchar();
   }
for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
{
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}  
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read and answer my question

Comment: [atoi()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) function is expecting a null terminated string as parameter, not a char.

Comment: I'd replace that for loop by simply `arr[num]++;`

Comment: @MartinVerjans why does the function  work properly initially then?

Comment: @Curfew a string is an array of characters with a NULL terminator (`\0`) at the end.  you don't supply a NULL-terminated string in your `atoi()` call, so this is undefined behaviour at best.

Comment: `char text;` **-->>** `int text;` (or EOF will not work properly)

Comment: @Tau Thanks for clarifying on that, so even if it did work in some cases it can be considered undefined behaviour?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's called undefined behaviour.  See **Andrew Henle**'s comment on his answer.

Comment: @Curfew -- the code is calling `atoi()` after each `char` is entered, and `text` points to the entered `char` in each case. The byte following `text` may be `\0` in some cases, and code might appear to work sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the `atoi()` documentation in the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.2):

> The atoi, atol, and atoll functions convert the **initial portion of the string pointed to by nptr** to int, long int, and long long int representation, respectively.

Note the bolded part.

Given

```
char text;
```

this code invokes undefined behavior because the address passed to `atoi()` is not that of a string:

```
int num = atoi(&text);
```

One fix would be:

```
char text[2];
text[1] = '\0';

// getchar() returns int, not char, in order
// to handle EOF properly
int input = getchar();
while(input != EOF)
{
    text[0] = input;
    if(isdigit(text[0]))
    {
        printf("text is %s ",text);
        int num = atoi(text);
```

That ensures that a **string** (a nul-terminated series of `char`) is passed to `atoi()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm still not sure why it worked in some cases.

Comment: @Curfew The first byte after `char text` was likely `'\0'` or the equivalent of a non-digit `char` value. Undefined behavior is undefined.  Note also the update to properly handle the fact that `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Curfew if this answer helped you, it would be much appreciated if you could *accept it as the answer* by clicking the gray ***check mark*** under the vote count.

Comment: @Tau sorry didn't know about that, marked it as the answer now

Answer (score 1):

- you don't need `atoi()` since you are dealing with single characters, not with strings
- getc()returns an int [0 .. 255 for actual characters, -1 for EOF]
- you can avoid a lot of `{}` braces by using `break` and `continue`

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    int arr[10] = {0};
    int text, num;
   while(1) {
        text = getchar();
        if (text == EOF) break;
        if (!isdigit(text)) continue;
        printf("text is %c ", text);
        num = text - '0'
        printf("num is %d\n ",num);
        arr[num]++;
        //printf("arr[%d] is %d\n", num, arr[num]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @wildpasser wow, never thought of break, continue and using arr[num]++ to replace the loop, thank you